# Why does the function have to return a char * but not a char array?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

```
char * printstring(void)
{
    return "my string";
}
```

Since what the function does is return a character array why do I have to state that my function returns `char*` and not `char[]` at the declaration.

Comment: Are you familiar with pointers and how they relate to arrays in C?

Comment: char * will return the starting address of memory block for your string. So that you can have access to the string out of this method as well.

Comment: A C function cannot return an array, although it may return a `struct` which contains an array.

Comment: This function should return `const char*` anyway.

Comment: @Rabbid76: If you mean "it will help detect illegal write-accesses", you are correct. But it is - unfortunately - not required in C for legacy reasons which should have been burried deeply since 20 years.

Comment: @templatetypedef I know that array names can be used as pointer, so myArray and &myArray[0] are the same thing

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes you're correct I was just in a hurry I guess :)

Comment: @ShewaleVishal Thanks for your answer it was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: You need to return the start address of the array to get access to the array which you can get using *. I don't think we can directly return arrays.

Comment: Instead you can return a pointer to an array.

Comment: E.g `const char (*printstring(void))[10]{
    return (const char(*)[10])"my string";
}` But this is limited and not easy to use.

Comment: "*Since what the function does is return a character array*" no, exactly not! It returns the address of the array's (as string here) 1st element (a `char` here).

Answer (score 7):

Because because of the the way C was designed, arrays are not first-class citizens in it. You can neither return them nor pass them to a function by value.

If you want achieve either of those things, you'll have to wrap the array in a struct.

```
struct ten_chars{ char chars[10]; };

struct ten_chars printstring(void)
{
    return (struct ten_chars){"my string"};
}
```

Comment: I still haven't got to structs but just to reference your answer later are you saying there's another way I could achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @BareWithImANoob Yes. I added the code. It's probably a bad idea, though. Returning large objects in general is, in my opinion.

Comment: In `main` you could have `printf("%s\n", printstring().chars);` But it is an ugly way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

The string literal `"my string"` does have array type. Note that `sizeof "my string"` will evaluate to `10`, as expected for an array that holds 10 `char`s (including the `'\0'`). You can think of `"my string"` as an identifier that identifies an array, and decays to a pointer to the first element of the array in most expressions (but not in, e.g., `sizeof` expressions).

So, in the return statement, `"my string"` decays to a pointer to the first element of the array that holds the characters of the string literal (and the null terminator). It is this pointer that is returned from the function, and this is why the return type must be `char *`.

For the record, it is not even possible to return an array from a function in C, though you can return a pointer to an array. You can also return a `struct` that contains an array field from a function.

Take a look at this example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * getstring(void);

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", getstring());

    return 0;
}

char * getstring(void)
{
    printf("sizeof \"my string\": %zu\n", sizeof "my string");
    printf("*(\"my string\" + 1): %c\n", *("my string" + 1));

    return "my string";
}
```

Program output:

```
sizeof "my string": 10
*("my string" + 1): y
my string
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that that "my string" decays to a pointer cause I didn't have that in mind

Comment: @BareWithImANoob-- sure... that seemed like the answer to the question, "why does the function have to return a `char *` but not a `char` array?"

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, C doesn't allow you to define a function that returns an array type; something like

```
char printstring(void)[10] { return "my string"; }
```

simply isn't allowed, and the compiler will yell at you over it.

Secondly, because what you are returning isn't an array.

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

The expression `"my string"` has type "10-element array of `char`".  Since it isn't the operand of either the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, and since it isn't being used to initialize an array of `char` in a declaration, it "decays" to an expression of type `char *`.  Its value is the address of the first character in the string, and that address value is what your function is actually returning.

This is by design - it was Ritchie's way of kind-of-sort-of preserving B's array semantics in C.  However, it means that array expressions in C do not retain their array-ness in most circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

In C it is not allowed to assign to an array variable.

```
char a[] = "test";
char b[5] = a; /* ILLEGAL */
```

So why then would one want to defined a function returning an array, if its result could be assigned to anything?

Answer (score -2):

Disclaimer: this is not intended as an exact answer to the question since it is about `c++`, not `c`. But i thought that it could be interesting in context of this discussion.

In `c++` there is a way to return a reference to an array which could look like the following:

```
static const char (&func())[12]  {
    return "hello world";
}
```

This is similar to returning a pointer and does not copy the values. But it is **not** possible in plain `c`.

Comment: I read your disclaimer. Disclaiming irrelevancy doesn't absolve it